# Share Images and text using whatsapp in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, base64, share, whatsapp

I'm using react native 0.59 to develop my application. I've tried both "Share" functions from react native core library and react-native-share. But the problem is sharing text and base64 image with Whatsapp in IOS. Following are the share options I'm using:

```
{
   title: "App Titme",
   url: this.selectedShareImg,
   message: "promotional message",
   type: "image/jpeg"
}
```

After going through several posts in the stack overflow, I noticed that both url and message together are not working for whatsapp, if fact it should be either only the url or otherwise only the message would appear. This problem only occurs in IOS, not in Android.

Is anyone managed to find a workaround to send both base64 image and the message in whatsapp?

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916